# Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\' is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, access-denied

I have written a c# application using LogParser to read IIS Log files.application works fine in my development machine but on server i get the following error.

```
Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\' is denied
```

how can i correct it?

**EDIT**

I tried to add Relevant permissions to intpub folder but i can not add a new user(ISUSR,NETWORK SERVICES or ASPNET)

because it doesn't show the add button only shows Edit.plz see image

[image]

Comment: By ensuring the user under which your application is running has the correct access to the said folder.

Comment: ASPNET account needs read write permission.

Comment: Did you check that the log file isnt marked as read only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking the `Edit` button and confirming the subsequent UAC prompt brings up a dialog that allows you add or edit users and groups and their permissions.

Comment: ohh sorry my bad.i have added the user accounts but still not working